# R flextable function flextable_to_rmd results in different data

Tags: image, conditional-statements, r-markdown, flextable

I am using compose in flextable to add conditional icons based on a cell value. A reproducible example is here:

```
demo<-flextable(head(starwars), col_keys=c("name","eye_color")) %>% 
  theme_booktabs()%>%
   compose(j="eye_color",i = ~ eye_color=="blue",   value = as_paragraph(as_image(img.file_Y, width = .15, height = .15))) %>%
   compose(j="eye_color",i = ~ eye_color=="yellow",   value = as_paragraph(as_image(img.file_G, width = .15, height = .15))) %>% 
   compose(j="eye_color",i = ~ eye_color=="red",   value = as_paragraph(as_image(img.file_R, width = .15, height = .15)))
```

When I render the table in html, the icons show up as expected based on the conditions.
However when I use flextable_to_rmd, the result is unexpected; the icons change and only the last condition (red) applies incorrectly to all rows.

```
flextable_to_rmd(demo)
```

Am I using compose incorrectly? I don't understand why the flextable_to_rmd function is interacting with the compose function. Thanks for any tips

*resulting pdf table after flextable_to_rmd*

[image: resulting pdf table after flextable_to_rmd]

*html version (correct) of table*

[image: html version (correct) of table]